# How to update xtick and xticklabel in for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure

Imagine a = 1:1000, b = sin(a) and we want to segment this data with segment_length = 100 and plot only each segment and shift the segment with segment_length/2 in for loop. I want to plot a figure in a for loop in which xtick and xticklabel update in each loop: 1st loop is 1-100, 2nd is 51-150, 3rd is 101-200 and so on. In the following code I just plot the interested data in each loop but xtick and xticklabel do not change.

```
a = 1:1000;
b = sin(a);
segment_length = 100;
shift = segment_length/2;
seg_no = 1000/shift;
start = 1;
en = segment_length; 
for i = 1 : seg_no-1 
    seg = b(start : en)
    plot(seg)
    start = shift + start 
    en = shift + en
end
```

Comment: Use the `plot(x,y)` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

note that you are not providing any information of the x-coordinates to Matlab. Thus, it must assume that your index always starts at 1. That is why they don't change.
Here is the solution

```
a = 1:1000;
b = sin(a);
segment_length = 100;
shift = segment_length/2;
seg_no = 1000/shift;
start = 1;
en = segment_length; 
for i = 1 : seg_no-1 
    idx = start:en;
    seg = b(idx);
    plot(idx,seg)
    start = shift + start; 
    en = shift + en;

    drawnow % force matlab to draw/update the figure
    pause(0.1) % / s | pause for 0.1 seconds
end
```

Note that I used the commands `drawnow` forcing Matlab to update the figure before proceeding. I also added `pause()` to define how long Matlab should wait to better see the updated figure.